# Test no-bandwidth even with valid IP

Tags: lua, wifi, nodemcu

I am using the **nodeMCU ESP8266 12E** board and I can successfully connect to my wifi network and test for an IP. The problem is, having an IP does not necessarily imply that there is bandwidth available. May be the ISP is down and my router still gives the ESP8266 a valid IP.

How do I deal with this?

I have been playing around with the code below to see how it responds **when I unplug the wire from my modem to the router** to simulate a "**NO-Bandwidth**" situation. I thought [STA_DHCP_TIMEOUT](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/wifi/#wifieventmonregister) would hacve addressed it automatically but its not working like i think it is. Forgive my ignorance as I am a complete novice in Lua and the NodeMCU api.

```
     wifi.eventmon.register(wifi.eventmon.STA_CONNECTED, function(T) 
     print("wIfI Connected")
     end)

     wifi.eventmon.register(wifi.eventmon.STA_DISCONNECTED, function(T) 
     print("wIfI Disconnected")
     end)

     wifi.eventmon.register(wifi.eventmon.STA_GOT_IP, function(T) 
     print("wIfI Got an IP")
     end)

     wifi.eventmon.register(wifi.eventmon.STA_DHCP_TIMEOUT, function() 
     print("DHCP TIMEOUT")
     end)

    wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
    wifi.sta.config("mySSID","myPassword")
    print(wifi.sta.getip())
```

The image below shows the output. can someone please advise how to sense "NO-Bandwidth" while i have a valid IP?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am a complete novice in Lua and the NodeMCU api

By "no-bandwidth" you seem to mean no internet connection, right? If so, then this question seems fairly unrelated to either of the two. IMO it's more of a basic networking question.

- "DHCP timeout" means the device timed out acquiring an IP address.
- "Got IP" means that one of the components of your network infrastructure (the DHCP server) was reachable and assigned an IP address to your device.

As you noted this doesn't necessarily mean the device can actually connect to the internet. If the router acts as DHCP server and the modem, connected to the router, provides internet access it's understandable that the device won't have internet access if you disconnect the two.

To detect whether the internet is reachable from your device you need to try to connect to a server out there. With NodeMCU the easiest is to send a [GET request](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/http/#httpget) to a known resource and see whether you get a response. You'd obviously need the HTTP module for that.

```
http.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", nil, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```

**Update 20181130**

It's never too late to improve ones own answers later...Even easier than using the HTTP module would be to attempt a DNS resolution like so:

```
net.dns.resolve("www.google.com", function(sk, ip)
    if (ip == nil) then print("DNS fail! Maybe not connected to the internet.") else print(ip) end
end)
```

Comment: Thank you, now I know where to focus my research. On my website hosting server, I will create a special url to do this test so the ESP8266 can call it directly. Many thanks